# How to set default workspaces at boot when using spawnOn for startup apps?

Tags: haskell, xmonad

## Hi Everyone,

I have **dual monitor setup** and I use `spawnOn` to start some *messenger apps* on the dedicated workspace lets say it will be 7th. The problem is when I do that **Xmonad** starts *7th workspace* by default on one of my monitors, how to start *Xmonad** in this way so that it has **empty workspaces 1 and 2** assigned to both monitors while having messenger apps start silently on *7th workspace* or any other dedicated workspace?

### My layouts config section:

```hs
mySpacing :: Integer -> l a -> XMonad.Layout.LayoutModifier.ModifiedLayout Spacing l a
mySpacing i = spacingRaw False (Border i i i i) True (Border i i i i) True

tiled    =   renamed [Replace "tiled"]
           $ smartBorders
           $ limitWindows 12
           $ mySpacing 5
           $ ResizableTall 1 (3/100) (1/2) []
full    =    renamed [Replace "full"]
           $ noBorders
           $ Full
magnify  =   renamed [Replace "magnify"]
           $ magnifier
           $ limitWindows 4
           $ mySpacing 5
           $ ResizableTall 1 (3/100) (1/2) []

myLayout = T.toggleLayouts full $ desktopLayoutModifiers $ onWorkspaces ["7"] magnify $ myDefaultLayout
  where
    myDefaultLayout = tiled
                  ||| magnify
```

#### My startupHook:

```hs
myStartupHook = do
    spawnOn   "7" "messengerApp &"
```

Thanks in advance for even reading this...
Here is full [config](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/asolopovas/dotfiles/master/.config/xmonad/xmonad.hs)

Comment: Please show a complete config that exhibits this problem. Bonus points if you spend a bit of time minimizing it. In any case xmonad is a complicated beast and the other bits of your config have a bearing on this behavior.

Comment: @DanielWagner I have added a link to my config... it is not long and kind of basic to be honest.

Comment: Hm, okay. That config kills my hypothesis (that you were using dynamic workspaces and didn't have enough static ones). So I'm not sure of the answer -- but wanted to let you know that I saw your update and appreciated it.